# Number of dimensions of Iris dataset?

Tags: arrays, matlab, dimensions

Does anyone familiar with the [*Iris* data set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_flower_data_set)? Please correct me if I am wrong, but this data set has 4 dimensions. However, `ndims` returns only 2. How is that possible?

Comment: where from did you obtain the dataset? how is it stored?

Comment: Features and dimensions mean slightly different things in the machine learning and programming worlds, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

It has 2 dimensions, one of length 150 and the other of length 4 (not including Species data). Perhaps you want to use `size` instead of `ndims`?

Comment: size will return 150 4. which corresponds to your answer above. I just still do not understand why does dimension equal to 2? I have tried searching for the meaning of the dimensions. It does tell me that, dimension is quite similar with an array.

Comment: @dee You can add an additional parameter to your `size` call to get just the number of columns, ie `size(iris,2)`. `ndims` gives the number of dimensions of the array, ie the dimensionality of the "hypercube" it can conceptualised as. This is obviously pretty meaningless for a flat database, as the answer will always be 2.